# Google-assistant Template configuration parameters

Tags: google-sheets, actions-on-google, google-home

I’m making a personality test for the google assistant based on the personality Quiz app template.(using Google Sheet).

Sometimes the app starts by saying: Welcome to the……"  and occasionally it start by saying “Let’s play the…..”
Can I force the app to say “Welcome to the… each time it starts ?   Similary I would like to prevent the app from saying: "Do you want to play the Quiz again ?" Because it isn't a Quiz.

My hope is that this can be fixed by changing the configuration parameters in the google sheet.  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The templates are designed to simplify the VUI and remove the need for you to write code. As such, there is some customization that is not available, such as the welcome and the ending message.